# finding a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find a polynomial with rational coefficients so that

$$ c = \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt[5]{1 - \sqrt[3]{7}} } $$

This is my attempt:

We have $(1/2-c)^2 = \sqrt{ ... }^2 $ so

$$ (1/2-c)^2 = 2 +  \sqrt[5]{1 - \sqrt[3]{7}} $$

But here, this polynomial gets very complicated. Is there an easier way to do this or this is the only way?

Comment: Wolfram suggests this is the only way, there are no simplifications and the minimal polynomial is of degree $30$.

Comment: When you have a bunch of nested radicals like this, it can often be very hard to find the minimal polynomial because the minimal polynomial is so convoluted. However, I think your method is the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: $(c - 1/2)^2 - 2=c^2-c-\frac{7}{4}$. Take the 5th power: $c^{10}-5c^9+\frac{5}{4}c^8+25c^7-\frac{135}{8}c^6-\frac{463}{8}c^5+\frac{945}{32}c^4+\frac{1225}{16}c^3-\frac{1715}{256}c^2-\frac{12005}{256}c-\frac{16807}{1024}$. Finally subtract 1, cube and add 7. $c^{30}-15c^{29}+\frac{315}{4}c^{28}-\frac{175}{2}c^{27}-\frac{11235}{16}c^{26}+\frac{37947}{16}c^{25}+\dots-\frac{5661753274423}{1073741824}=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$x=a-\sqrt{b+\sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}}}\Rightarrow (((x-a)^2+b)^5-1)^3+7=0$$ There is no problem even if it is tedious to finish.

A true proble could be with $$x=\sqrt[5]a+\sqrt[3]b$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to note that $c$ has at most $30$ conjugates:

$$c_{ijk} = \frac{1}{2} + (-1)^i \sqrt{2+\omega^j\sqrt[5]{1-\tau^k\sqrt[3]{7}}}$$

Here $\omega$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity, $\tau$ is a primitive $3$-rd root of unity, and $i \in \{0,1\}, j\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}, k\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Taking the product $\prod_{i,j,k} (X-c_{ijk})$ is guaranteed to give you a monic polynomial with integer coefficients with $c$ as a root.